# CSS Divs keep overlapping

Tags: css, html, overlay, overlapping

I am making a login screen with two sections. The login section `(500x350)` and a register section `(500x350)`.

The problem is that everytime I resize the window the two divs keep overlapping.
 I have tried `float, display:block, display:inline, Overflow automatic en hidden`.

What could I try next?

Comment: if you have a tried source code please share in jsfiddle your source code

Comment: can it be possible that you used % value in width of parent div instead of pixels ?

Comment: Impossible to help you without seeing your HTML and CSS!

Answer (score 1):

The height and width are more than the window size. Try using % instead of px. See [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/ahy52/) You can increase the % according to your requirement.

```
       <div id="login">
          Login Section
       </div>
       <div id="register">
          Register Section
       </div>
       #login{
         background:yellow;
         height:50%;
         width:35%;
         float:left;
       }
       #register{
         background:pink;
         height:50%;
         width:35%;
         float:left;
       }
```